# Justify text inside span tags

Tags: css

I have a markup like this

```
<div><span>My name is</span><span>ABC</span></div>
```

How can I justify this text on the whole line?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
<div style="text-align: justify"><span>My name is</span><span>ABC</span></div>
```

Pretty simple, the spans will not break the text justification. If text is only one line long, it is not possible to justify it across the entire line. As well, the last line of a paragraph cannot be justified across the entire line either.

Comment: This worked like a charm for me. I have 12 spans with long texts and this solution allows me to align them nicely.

Answer (score 14):

My solution:

```
<span style="text-align: justify; display:block;">Your Text</span>
```

Comment: That would not work well with multiple `<span>` tags.

Comment: Works very well for text within a span, not for multiple spans.

Comment: thank you, I have a question, why you used display: block?

Comment: The key is the display:block;

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to justify a single line of text, but it might get ugly. It is possible by using the CSS3 `text-justify` property that were added for Asian and non Latin languages.

There's the link for a description of the properties : http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#text-justify

Comment: This is a predominantly English website, and therefore whatever resources you link to should also be in English. I've replaced your link with one to the official CSS3 draft specifications